# Most final appearances without winning a title in one season

Tags: football, trivia, records

Carsten Ramelow, Bernd Schneider and Oliver Neuville lost three finals in 2002:

- DFB Pokal (2-4 to Schalke 04, with Leverkusen)
- Champions League (1-2 to Real Madrid, with Leverkusen)
- FIFA World Cup (0-2 to Brazil with Germany)

They even ended up on the 2nd place of the Bundesliga with Leverkusen in that year, but since the league doesn't have playoffs they didn't lose a final there.

Did anyone ever beat this unfortunate streak by losing more than 3 finals within one season?

Comment: Wikipedia article on treble [used to have]([Treble (association football)](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=The_Treble&oldid=279265732#Treble_Horror)) a section on "treble horror". You can find some past discussion about the removal [on the talk page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Talk:Treble_(association_football)). However, this is different - since it includes finishing 2nd in the domestic league.

Comment: @Martin thanks for the link, but it shows only teams, so national team appearances are not included (like my example players losing the WC final  as well as every other final with their club).

Comment: the great Michael Ballack also.